# Script to dynamically generate XML file based on most Git commit contents (Salesforce CI)

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, continuous-integration, git

I'm using DX for my Continuous Integration, but post-scratch org when I want to deploy into a traditional sandbox for staging, I'm struggling with an automated way to deploy only the new commits (as opposed to ALL of the metadata) in my Dev Branch. Is anyone using a script that archives this (dynamically creates the package.xml based on the most recent commit)?

The use case is that without this, I am deploying ALL the metadata each time, hitting the limit of 10,000 files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the legacy/community maintained [ForceCLI](https://force-cli.heroku.com/) project to do delta deployments when not using Salesforce DX. It's pretty easy to get a basic workflow going using a shell script.

You can do something like this:

```
git diff [...] --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | force push -f -
```

What this does is get a list of changed files between two Git revisions (you'd replace `[...]` with either a reference to a start and end commit, or an expression like `HEAD~1` for a delta of `HEAD` against the previous commit) and list their paths. It then pipes those paths into `force`, which will automatically construct a `package.xml` and run the delta deployment.

I've found a few issues with ForceCLI around delta-deploying unpacked Static Resources and Lightning Components (I believe the latter has already been fixed, but may not have been released yet), but those issues are more or less easily worked around with a little Bash. For static resources, I use a script that zips them up and then pipes the `git diff` output through `sed` to squash all references to static resource elements to a reference to the zip file, e.g.

```
sed -E 's#^src/staticresources/([^/]+)/.+#src/staticresources/\1\.resource#
```

Note that one thing this approach *doesn't* handle is deletions. I delete metadata so rarely that I have not invested the effort to script delta deletions. Since deletions can be run either pre- or post-deploy and sometimes need to be one or the other, I've felt the effort to introspect the desired delete operation off of a commit message was more than it was worth.

Comment: In my case, I'm already installing the Salesforce CLI on the server... do you know if I could use sfdx force:mdapi:deploy  in lieu of the force push command with the legacy CLI?

Comment: As far as I know, you'd have to generate the delta `package.xml` yourself to use `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy`. I don't believe it has functionality to do that, although I'd be delighted to be wrong.

Comment: I'll give it a whirl. The one thing I hate about this is that I really liked the JWT auth flow that the sfdx CLI has. Based on what I've seen, I'll have to do the old fashioned password+token for this flow. Aside from that, it should work fine and I technically don't need the new CLI for anything else.

Comment: While I have not used it, ForceCLI claims to support JWT -- see `force help login`: `force login --connected-app-client-id <my-consumer-key> -u username -key jwt.key`

Answer (score 2):

There is now [sfdx-git-delta](https://github.com/scolladon/sfdx-git-delta) which allows you provide which commits you'd like to generate a deployment for. It can identify the *changed* metadata since a reference commit & build the `destructiveChanges.xml` from the *deleted* (or renamed) metadata

---

*Install*

```bat
sfdx plugins:install sfdx-git-delta
```

*Git output of diff between latest commit (`HEAD`) and the previous commit (`HEAD^`)*

```
sfdx sgd:source:delta --to "HEAD" --from "HEAD^" --output "."
```

The above generates 2 useful artifacts

1. A `package.xml` file inside a `package` folder. This `package.xml` will contain the added/changed metadata to deploy
2. A `destructiveChange.xml` file, inside a `destructiveChanges` folder. This contains the removed/renamed metadata to delete from the target org.

As opposed to the above generated files, you can have it generate a *source* folder by using `--generate delta` in the delta command. This is useful for objects where you just want to deploy what specifically changed vs. the entire sub-folder.

*Deploy the delta metadata*

```cmd
sfdx force:source:deploy -x package/package.xml --postdestructivechanges destructiveChanges/destructiveChanges.xml
```

*Or split the deploy operations up*

```sh
echo "--- package.xml generated with added and modified metadata ---"
cat package/package.xml
echo
echo "---- Deploying added and modified metadata ----"
sfdx force:source:deploy -x package/package.xml

echo "--- destructiveChanges.xml generated with deleted metadata ---"
cat destructiveChanges/destructiveChanges.xml
echo
echo "--- Deleting removed metadata ---"
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d destructiveChanges --ignorewarnings
```